# Некорректное копирование многомерного массива в массив

Tags: c, массивы, разработка-игр

Приветствую, пишу морской бой для академии, вот работающий кусок моего проекта-наброска, проблема в том, что копируется только первая строка двумерного массива deck5 в map.

```
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <time.h>
/*
#include <conio.h>
*/

#define s 13
#define c 28

char deck5[3][7] = {
    { '0', '0', '0', '0', '0', '0', '0', '0' },
    { '0', '*', '*', '*', '*', '*', '*', '0' },
    { '0', '0', '0', '0', '0', '0', '0', '0' }
};

char map[s][c]=
{
  "  0123456789    0123456789 ",
  "  ----------    ---------- ",
  "0|          | 0|          |",
  "1|          | 1|          |",
  "2|          | 2|          |",
  "3|          | 3|          |",
  "4|          | 4|          |",
  "5|          | 5|          |",
  "6|          | 6|          |",
  "7|          | 7|          |",
  "8|          | 8|          |",
  "9|          | 9|          |",
  "  ----------    ---------- ",
};

void show(char (*pmap)[c])
{
  int i,j;

  for(i=0; i<s; ++i)
    {
      for(j=0; j<c; ++j)
        {
          printf("%c",pmap[i][j]);
        }
      printf("\n");
    }
}

h_ship5(char (*pmap)[c])
{
int i=0,j=0,x=0,y=0,ii=0,jj=0,yes=0;
 do//зацикливает проверку правильности расположения корабля
    {

      x=rand()%7+2;
      y=rand()%7+2;
      yes=0;

        for(; j<(y+5); j++)
          {
            if(pmap[x][j]==' ')
              {
                yes++;

              }
          }
    }
  while(yes<5);
    x--,y--;
  i=x,j=y;

for(;i<(x+3);i++){
    if(jj==7){
    ii++;
    jj=0;}
    for(;j<(y+7);j++){
        jj++;
if(pmap[i][j]==' ')
        pmap[i][j]=deck5[ii][jj];
    }
}

return pmap;

}

int main()
{
  srand( (unsigned)time( NULL ) );

  char*pmap=map;

  pmap=h_ship5(pmap);
  show(pmap);
  return 0;
}
```

Вот простое копирование массива в массив, но копируется почему то, только первая строка.

```
#define s 13
#define c 28
#define a 3
#define b 8

char deck5[a][b] = {
      "0000000",
      "0*****0",
      "0000000",};

char map[a][b] = {
      "1111111",
      "1*****1",
      "1111111",};

int main(int argc, char** argv) {
int i = 0, j = 0;

for (; i <  3; i++) {
        for (; j < 7; j++) {
                map[i][j] = deck5[i][j];
        //if(j==7)deck5[i][j]='\0'; или map[i][j]='\0'; или оба варианта вместе не помогают
        }
    }

 for (i = 0; i < a; ++i) {
        for (j = 0; j < b; ++j) {
            printf("%c", map[i][j]);
        }
        printf("\n");
    }

    return (EXIT_SUCCESS);
}
```

Варнинги компилятора:

```
 \Desktop\test\test_fight\main.c||In function 'show':|

    \Desktop\test\test_fight\main.c|41|warning: implicit declaration of function 'printf'|

    \Desktop\test\test_fight\main.c|41|warning: incompatible implicit declaration of built-in function 'printf'|

    \Desktop\test\test_fight\main.c|43|warning: incompatible implicit declaration of built-in function 'printf'|

    \Desktop\test\test_fight\main.c|49|warning: return type defaults to 'int'|

    \Desktop\test\test_fight\main.c||In function 'h_ship5':|

    \Desktop\test\test_fight\main.c|82|warning: return makes integer from pointer without a cast|

    \Desktop\test\test_fight\main.c||In function 'main':|

    \Desktop\test\test_fight\main.c|91|warning: initialization from incompatible pointer type|

    \Desktop\test\test_fight\main.c|93|warning: passing argument 1 of 'h_ship5' from incompatible pointer type|

    \Desktop\test\test_fight\main.c|48|note: expected 'char (*)[28]' but argument is of type 'char *'|

    \Desktop\test\test_fight\main.c|93|warning: assignment makes pointer from integer without a cast|

    \Desktop\test\test_fight\main.c|94|warning: passing argument 1 of 'show' from incompatible pointer type|

    \Desktop\test\test_fight\main.c|33|note: expected 'char (*)[28]' but argument is of type 'char *'|

    ||=== Build finished: 0 errors, 9 warnings ===|
```

Comment: А в чем заключается эта некорректность?

Comment: У меня создалось такое впечатление, что происходит выход за пределы массива deck. Попробуйте проверить индексы, сделайте тестовый вывод, например.

Comment: @abrakadabra А Вы свой код пробовали транслировать? У меня компилятор выдал 7 предупреждений и 2 замечания.

Comment: VorobyevEvgeniy- печатается только первая строка, или цифры от 1до7.
insolor - все нормально.
alexlz - спасибо, надо посмотреть.

Comment: `implicit declaration of function 'printf'` -- нет прототипа printf (он находится в stdio.h)

`warning: return type defaults to 'int' In function 'h_ship5'` -- нет описания типа h_ship5. Лучше добавить.

Ну и т.д. Лучше исправить, проблем будет меньше.

Answer (score 3):

```
char deck5[3][7] = { "0000000",
    "0*****0",
    "0000000",
};
```

Смотрим на данный код. имеем массив 3 на 7 но ты заполняешь его не символами, а строкой которая имеет в себе 7 символов и как все С строки заканчивается '\0' нуль символом.
То есть у тебя '\0' символ уходит за пределы массива, а раз массивы располагаются друг за другом то нуль символ попадает в начало нового массива и получается не то что вам надо.
Попробуйте сделать так.

```
char deck5[3][7] = { 
    { '0', '0', '0', '0', '0', '0', '0' },
    { '0', '*', '*', '*', '*', '*', '0' },
    { '0', '0', '0', '0', '0', '0', '0' }
};
```

это первое что я увидел.

Comment: Спасибо, почти работает, выводит только первый ряд символов, может знаете как это решить? я пробовал добавить в цикле перенос строки, но это не работает.

Comment: я добавил к вопросу варнинги компилятора

Comment: у меня была ошибочка, я сам заполнял массив по 8 символов, так что исправь как сейчас.
И ещё я не понял как у тебя функция h_ship5(char (*pmap)[c]) возвращает значение, но в определение не указано что должно возвращать и у меня просто не компилируется твой код.
Может тебе проще будет сделать данный массив глобально и не надо передавать указатель но на него и ничего не надо возвращать, а напрямую с ним работать.

Comment: не работает все равно, для эксперимента я создал два двумерных массива одинаковой размерности и по тому же принципу попробовал скопировать один в другой, но  копируется также, только первая строка. Я не могу понять в чем дело... я к вопросу добавил код - копирование массива.

Comment: @Roman Goriachevskiy
Я нашел ответ. В условии цикла копирования массива, нужно i и j присвоить значение. В моем нерабочем коде i и j присваивается x и y, ПЕРЕД входом в цикл, получается что это нужно делать именно в условии цикла. Мда, я из за этого потерял неделю времени, мог бы уже написать игру.

for(i=x,ii=0;i<(x+3);i++,ii++){

    for(j=y,jj=0;j<(y+7);j++,jj++){
if(pmap[i][j]==' ')
        pmap[i][j]=deck5[ii][jj];
    }
}